# Getting error in google reverse image search

Tags: android, webview

Hey I have one web view in my android application and I'm displaying it with following url `https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?&image_url=+'my-image-path'` but the problem is that I'm getting following error:

```
About This page
our system have detected unusual traffic from your computer network. this page checks to see if it's really you'r sending the request and not a robot.
```

Comment: You're going to need to use a Google API if you are going to reference their data in your app. Of course it is going to be flagged if you are embedding their free search functionality within your app. I suggest you look into [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview)

Comment: @JAYPANCHAL Because it took Google's anti-bot system a day to detect that you're using their system Illicitly. You'll have to use their API to keep on doing what you do.

Comment: You could get creative and try to circumvent Google's protocols but they will eventually catch on and shut you down one way or another. You are violating their terms of service and I would highly recommend using one of their approved methods to serve their data in your app if you want to continue leveraging Google's search products on an Android (Google) app